# Arrays in Heap in CLR

Tags: arrays, object, heap-memory, clr

I have a figure below:

[image]

And my question is that the objects in Array in Heap are stored in where it says "Object Reference" with its values, properties,etc. **OR** these "Object Reference" parts hold only references to another Heap Address where everything of the particular object is stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An object reference is exactly that – a *reference* to an object stored elsewhere.

Note that only classes are stored as object references; structs (value type) are stored inline.

Comment: So you say "Value types would be stored in the same slot whereas objects are stored in different address but the slot only has the reference of the address where the object body is stored"

Comment: Correct.  (except that the word `same` isn't relevant)